# Advice, how to save element state for each page (js, jquery,css)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have side menu, position on the left side of the page (on every page). It can be hide and opened. And I've notice that every time menu closing when user is leaving the page and go to other page. What I want to do - is to save side menu position for every user. So it can decide by his self, if he want it opened or closed.

So I've wrote Js what send cookie (opened/closed value) but I don't like how it perform.

The basic position for menu is closed. And with this JS it just reopen every time user visiting page (with animation and I don't like this).

So, my html have wrapper and looks like this: `#wrapper.toggled`

Js for toggle:

```
$('#show-sidebar').click (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()
    $('#wrapper').toggleClass('toggled')
```

So any advice how can I do it

Comment: do you have a root controller ?

Comment: You should render your section with `toggled` class applied if some conditions (from cookies or from server state) are meets.

Comment: What is performing as not expected exactly ?

Comment: @MiteshPant I have application controller, yes

Comment: then you can have an object where you can save the last state on that particular element

Comment: @VadimB You mean forget JS for this purpose, and check it before render?

Comment: Yes, you have this information on backend as I understand, so you can render already toggled

Comment: @VadimB I'm so stupid. Ty!